# Removing special characters php

Tags: php

I need to remove special characters and white space form $data.
I tried trim and preg_replace without success...

`$data  = 'ello€ Wo@r"ldČ2';`

$remove =  '    ~"#$%&()=?*+-@][€Ł|/');,:*/     ';

Final data need to be like that elloWorldC2

Comment: why do you need to remove parts of your data at random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removes all special charecters  `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/s', '', $data);`

Comment: Works

`$c = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_. *@]/s', '', $data);`

**But how to get just one @ if I have more?**

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do if you want to allow only letters, numbers, and underscores is this:

```
$replace = preg_replace("/[^\w]{1,}/", "", $data);
```

Comment: `{1,}` is identical to `+`.  but please don't do this; it's usually a clumsy way to solve whatever the real problem is, and will cause bugs for people who care about more than just English letters

Answer (score 0):

You can do this steps:

$c = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.@]/s', '', $data); // remove all special characters except letter, numbers, dot, bottom line and @.

$count = substr_count($c, "@"); // @ count

$c = preg_replace('/@/s', '', $c, $count-1); // remove all @ except one.